# Where is function for delete address from admin of customers

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, customer-address, delete

I want to know function logic location, when customer address is remove from admin section. The cross button is present in "Addresses" tab in left navigation of Customer Information. After click  cross button and hit save or save and continue Edit which functions calls in both cases for remove customer address which are assigned to customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\CustomerController.php`
and action `saveAction`

**Code :**

```
// Mark not modified customer addresses for delete
            foreach ($customer->getAddressesCollection() as $customerAddress) {
                if ($customerAddress->getId() && !in_array($customerAddress->getId(), $modifiedAddresses)) {
                    $customerAddress->setData('_deleted', true);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yes looking for the same.